# How to get value from calling constructer?

Tags: java, class, oop, constructor

```
        import java.util.Date;
        
        class ch {
            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
        
                Date today = new Date();
        
                System.out.println(today);
        
            }
        
        }
```

The above code give current date as the output.

But , How is that possible ?

I just creating a new object. But , how the variable's value become the current date ?

I analyzed the date class but I couldn't understand.

Comment: The documentation says `Allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it represents the time at which it was allocated, measured to the nearest millisecond.`. The no-parameter constructor initializes the object with the current date and time.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use the `Date` class. It was always poorly designed and exactly for that reason was replaced by a number of classes in [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). Use for example `LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());` for today’s date in the default time zone of your JVM (since it is never the same date in all time zones). `now()` is a static method in the `LocalDate` class. Other than that I find that the code is clearer to read and not so mysterious as  `new Date();`.

Comment: Also just to make the outdated `Date` class even more confusing: There are really two "hidden" steps involved in your code printing today’s date. From `new Date()` you didn’t get the date but an object representing *the point in time* when the object was created. You read correctly: A `Date` cannot represent a date! Next when printing it you were implicitly calling its `toString` method. That method then figured out which date and time of day your `Date` object corresponded to in the default time zone of the JVM and printed that. It’s a complication that you should never struggle with, ever.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor of `java.util.Date` makes it happen.
When called without parameters it creates the object with a current date.
Here is an implementation of that constructor:

```java
 ...inside the class Date ...
 public Date() {
        this(System.currentTimeMillis());
 }
```

As you see it calls `System.currentTimeMillis()` method which returns the long that represents the current date

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/example/java-src/pkg/java/util/date-69836.html) you can find a source code of that class. Also pay attention to the java doc (documentation above the constructor) It clearly states that this is an expected behavior.